# Java Selenium: How is it possible to get a NoAlertPresentException from inside a UnhandledAlertException handler?

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Java selenium in order to control a browser (open up webpages, delete cookies, etc). Whenever I have an alert, I dismiss it as follows:

```
try

{

    webDriver.someFunc();

}

catch (UnhandledAlertException error)

{

    webDriver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();

}
```

Then, in some cases I get a `NoAlertPresentException` thrown when trying to dismiss the alert.

I do not understand, how is it possible that I get a `NoAlertPresentException` thrown from inside a `UnhandledAlertException` handler?????

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I too am getting the same error,but am unable to figure out why?

I tried this:

try

{

```
webDriver.someFunc();
webDriver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

}

catch (UnhandledAlertException error)

{

//Ignore

}

This should work.
Problem with your code probably is:
suppose you click on some button which opens an alert and you have put that in try block.As soon as unhandledalertexception is triggered(when alert is opened) it automatically dismisses your alert so that the next statement becomes invalid so the statement you have defined in catch block becomes invalid and it shows No alert found exception as the alert has already been dismissed.
But am still trying to figure out why unhandledalert exception is triggered at the first place.It is triggered all of a sudden for some alerts and doesnot show for all alerts.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Also you can try:DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities(); dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehavi‌​our.ACCEPT);driver=new FirefoxDriver(dc);            Also make sure you are handling alerts those that are defined by webdriver API..By that I mean the ones developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, i must say, that the concept of unhandled alert makes no sense to me, because alerts are triggered by actions. If you don't understand how the alert is triggered, you should discuss this with your developers and handle it the right way. That being said, take a look into DesiredCapabilities -> [CapapilityType -> UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.html#UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR)

Comment: First of all, as I said (at the top of this page): I am using Java selenium in order to control a browser (open up webpages, delete cookies, etc). Some pages trigger a browser alert, either when I open these pages or when I attempt to close them. I don't "have developers" (i.e., I AM the developer). Second, the link you provided brings to a constant Java String. How exactly does that help in solving the problem I have described? Thanks.

Comment: Something like: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT); driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

Comment: But i still stand with my first statement. "Some pages trigger a browser alert, either when I open these pages or when I attempt to close them." <- this is not unexpected, is it? Secondly, the link provided is documentation for Interface CapabilityType.